# Using universal references with non template types?

Tags: c++, overloading, c++20, forwarding-reference

I am building a simple piping operator for vectors, which the user would use like this (pseudocode):

```
auto x = std::vector{1,2,3} | push_back(10)
                            | push_back(100)
                            ;
```

Now I tried defining the piping operator like so:

```
template <typename T>
constexpr inline auto& operator| (std::vector<T>&& vec, std::invocable<std::vector<T>> auto&& func);
```

But now vec only to r-values (because the type of vec itself is not deduced) ! But I want it to bind to l-values too. How can I do it?

One ugly but functional solution would be to make another overload for my piping operator but with `std::vector<int>&`. However this is not scalable, ( 2 ^ n overloads for n arguments!), and I believe this is the very reason universal references were created.

How can I use universal references in this case?

Comment: Really `invocable<T>`, not `invocable<vector<T>>`? Presumably `push_back(100)` is a callable that takes a `vector<int>`, not a callable that takes an `int`?

Comment: @Barry yes you are right

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, you can use forwarding references.

```
template <typename T> inline constexpr bool is_vector = false;
template <typename ...P> inline constexpr bool is_vector<std::vector<P...>> = true;

template <typename T> requires is_vector<std::remove_cvref_t<T>>
constexpr auto &operator|(T &&vec, std::invocable<T> auto &&func);
```

Also, remember that operators should normally be created in the same namespace as one of their parameters, so that ADL can find them. But you can't touch `namespace std`...

Also, I don't like the idea of overloading an operator with neither parameter being a class that *you* created. Unless your users must explicitly opt-in for those operators by doing `using namespace ...;`.

Comment: That doesn't complete solve my problem, as I don't think you can overload the operator for other types now...

Comment: Yes your last point is perfectly valid. I will be putting them in a namespace called piping.

Comment: @SomeProgrammer No, this doesn't prevent you from overloading `|` for other types. C++20 `requires` is extra nice in this regard, but even the old `enable_if_t`-based SFINAE would work.

Comment: From cppreference "template<Incrementable T> 
void g(T) requires Decrementable<T>;
 
template<Decrementable T> 
void g(T) requires Incrementable<T>; // ill-formed, no diagnostic required"

Comment: Do I have to revert to SFINAE then to make it work?

Comment: @SomeProgrammer What, no. That cppreference quote says you can't redeclare a function with the **same** constraints but spelled differently. Of course you can overload the function if the constraints are different.

Comment: Ooooh ok. I'm so stupid! Thank you for explaining.